# Upper Mass Limit of Quark Stars

Tags: astrophysics, stars, quarks, neutron-stars

While there is no confirmation that quark stars exist, is there any theoretical limit analogous to (but different from) the [Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_limit) for neutron stars?

In other words, what is the maximum pressure for quark matter?

Comment: The limit would depend on the flavor mix and would be smaller than that for neutron stars.

Comment: Estimates for the limit for neutron stars vary by a factor of about two; since we know even less about the equation of state for quark matter, I'd expect any quark-star mass limit to be even more poorly constrained.

Comment: @dmckee [Structure of Quark Stars 2012](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1910) in table 1 say u,d,s quark stars have an upper limit of 2 solar mass and the limit for neutron stars is "same".  [Hydrostatic Equilibrium of Hypothetical Quark Stars 1970](http://ptp.oxfordjournals.org/content/44/1/291) says the limit is "much less" for quark stars (also u,d,s) than neutron stars.  So I'm confused.  I would think the newer reference is more correct, but I don't see why the limit would be the same for both.  And the newer reference is saying quark stars aren't bound by gravity in table 1.

Comment: Dave, I'm no expert in this area and will read your link with interest. My comment was fairly naive, and basically assumed that neutron degenerate equilibrium was be similar to a $u$, $d$ equilibrium but perhaps a little lower (at low momentum all the heavier quark content is fairly small, so probably similar thinking to the 1970 paper); and that higher heavy quark content would be denser could only make things more compact. That is to say I neglected the electric field issues that the 2012 abstract talks about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upper mass limit for a quark star depends on your assumptions and ranges between 1 and 2 solar masses (cf. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0101143) (arXiv link) from 2001). It seems to me that the reason for the similarity to neutron stars' mass range is that it *both* compact objects satisfy the [TOV equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation),
$$
\frac{dp}{dr}=-\frac{G}{r^2}\left[\rho+\frac{p}{c^2}\right]\left[M+4\pi r^2\frac{p}{c^2}\right]\left[1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right]^{-1}
$$
but with different equations of state.

For the quark star, according to the aforemention paper, the pressure is defined as
$$
p(\mu)=\frac{N_f\mu^4}{4\pi^2}\left[1-2\frac{\alpha_s}{\pi}-\left(G+N_f\ln\frac{\alpha_s}\pi+\left(11-\frac23N_f\right)\ln\frac{\bar{\Lambda}}{\mu}\right)\frac{\alpha_s^2}{\pi^2}\right]
$$
where $G\simeq10.4-0.536N_f+N_f\ln N_f$, $\alpha_s$ the [strong coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_constant#Weak_and_strong_coupling), $N_f$ the number of flavors (often taken as 3), $\mu$ the chemical potential, and $\bar{\Lambda}$ the [renormalization subtraction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization#Renormalized_and_bare_quantities) (my understanding of this term is minimal, but it seems to change the *size* of the mass-radius relation, but not the *shape*).